# Spring integration design information advice

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

We have app which has to process master and child records in almost real time. So for eg. when master record 1 is ready or in specific state, we need to get all its child records and submit to other system. Once all are submitted(success/failed), we need to change the state of their master record. Now whether child records successfully submitted or failed does not matter to us as far as we change the status of the master record.

Can someone suggest how this can be achived in spring integration? Or is it a good idea to use spring batch and spring integration together?

Comment: This is a very open question and you might get opiniated answers. You can achieve this with batch only, integration only or a combination of both. Personally I'd say it depends on how many master records and how many child per master you have.

Comment: We are talking about processing more than 1 million records(master+child) in 6 - 7 hrs.

Comment: In this case I'd definitely use Spring Batch cause otherwise implementing pause/resume functionality might be cumbersome. If you then also use integration for processing is up to you.